# Three Verbs in a clause with "zu"

Tags: translation, verb

I'm trying to express this idea in German:

> I would like to try to write it.

Since *würde* doesn't typically require *zu* in the infinitive, I'm confused about whether I need to have *zu* in this sentence. That is, I think it is one of these three options:

> Ich würde es gern zu schreiben versuchen.
>   Ich würde es gern schreiben versuchen.
>   Ich würde es gern versuchen, zu schreiben.

Comment: You're right that "würde gern"does not call for a "zu". But look at your sentence and ask yourself, which verb is connected to that. And then ask yourself to which verb the third verb is connected. And then ask yourself whether that one needs a "zu" or not. It doesn't matter what verbs are in a sentence. There can be hundreds. What matters is, which verb something is connected to directly. That determines what you need. Give it a try. You can do it.

Comment: Since I would write:

Ich versuche zu schreiben

I need zu because schreiben is attached to versuchen.

Thus, both

Ich würde es gern zu schreiben versuchen
and
Ich würde es gern versuchen, zu schreiben

should be acceptable. Am I correct?

Comment: Perfectly correct!

Comment: Another suggestion: Ich würde gern versuchen, es zu schreiben.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a translation word by word I would prefer:

> Ich würde gerne versuchen, es zu schreiben.

because the "it" in "I would like to try to write it" means that there is something specific you want to write about.

Even better sounds:

> Ich würde gerne versuchen, es aufzuschreiben.
>   (I would like to try to write it down.)

Comment: Duden explicitly allows a variant they call "Verschränkung" of the form: "Ich würde es gern zu schreiben versuchen." This is intellegible, but I've never used it and can't remember reading it anywhere other than in grammar example sentences.

Comment: Yes, "Ich würde es gern zu schreiben versuchen." is perfectly correct, but as you say: ... _can't remember reading it anywhere other than in grammar example sentences._ Germans don't often use that kind of construction.

Comment: *Aufzuschreiben* and *zu schreiben* slightly differ in meanings, though. Take calligraphy, I would never use *aufschreiben* when trying to write a chinese character calligrapicly.

Answer (score 2):

Referring to Emanuel's comment above both:

> Ich würde es gern zu schreiben versuchen.
>
> Ich würde es gern versuchen, zu schreiben.

are acceptable. This is because *schreiben* is connected to *versuchen* (rather than *würde*) so it requires a *zu*.